# Condition Variable notify_one notify_all

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, notify, condition-variable

I'm trying to learn the condition variables, and I'm stuck at the following example. I thought that `notify_one` on consumers should unlock only one waiting consumer. But after starting it repeatedly it seems to me that this isn't the case. I've changed `notify_one` into `notify_all` and haven't noticed a change in behavior. After the producer calls `notify_one` on consumers I can see `Get…` being written on screen by more then one consumer.

Why is this happening?

```
#include <iostream>           // std::cout
#include <thread>             // std::thread
#include <mutex>              // std::mutex, std::unique_lock
#include <condition_variable> // std::condition_variable
#include <chrono>
std::mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable produce,consume;

int cargo = 0;     // shared value by producers and consumers

void consumer () {
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
  while (cargo==0) consume.wait(lck);
  std::cout << "Get" << cargo << " "<< std::this_thread::get_id() << '\n';
  cargo--;
  produce.notify_one(); 
}

void producer (int id) {
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
  while (cargo!=0) produce.wait(lck);
    std::cout << "Push" << id <<  " "<< std::this_thread::get_id() << '\n';
    cargo += id;
    consume.notify_one();
}

void c () {
    while(1) {
    consumer();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    }
}
void p(int n) {
    while(1) {
        producer(n);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));
    }
}

int main ()
{
    std::thread consumers[5],producers[5];

    for (int i=0; i<5; ++i) {
       consumers[i] = std::thread(c);
       producers[i] = std::thread(p,i+1);
    }

    for (int i=0; i<5; ++i) {
       producers[i].join();
       consumers[i].join();
    }

    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Some consumers may see `cargo` already non-zero when they reach the while loop and therefore proceed without ever waiting at all.

Comment: @AlanStokes is right. Some of your producers make multiple items in one turn. This makes consumers that are started later directly pass the test and consume items without ever being suspended and the need to be woke up.

Comment: Thank you for the response :-) Is in this case, a better notify_all or notify_one? What notify should use consumer to invoke producer, and what producer to invoke consumer ?

Comment: @sweet_sugar As it was said, some of threads don't wait at all and the code does not work as you may expect. Try to add debug output in consumers: `while (cargo==0) { std::cout << "waiting " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl; consume.wait(lck); }` and you'll see the problem. Apart from that, if producer generates more than one work item and you have multiple consumers which process item without holding a lock (e.g. `sleep_for` in your example could be long processing and code under lock is preparaion) then `notify_all` looks natural, otherwise threads will wake up just to block again.

Comment: @frymode I don't think the consumer tread is still holding the lock while executing `sleep_for`. Note that when `consumer()` returns, the automatic variable `lck` defined in it was already destroyed. I agree that `notify_all` is appropriate here because of `sleep_for` that effectively prevents a single consumer thread from consuming the items non-stop.

Comment: @Lingxi Yep, that's what I meant. if "get" print in example (under lock) is not real work but `sleep_for` is (without lock) then it would be perfect, otherwise not so great.